# Sequelize: Querying a through table

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I'm trying to query a through table (Application) and paginate/order the results, but can't seem to get the logic quite right.

The Many-To-Many association:

```
// Applicants M:N Jobs (through Application)
Applicant.belongsToMany(Job, { through: Application });
Job.belongsToMany(Applicant, { through: Application });
```

I've queried Application, and then nested the queries for each side of the relation:

```
exports.getApplications = async (req, res, next) => {
    const index = req.query.index || 0;
    const limit = req.query.limit || 10;

    const applications = await Application.findAll({ limit: parseInt(limit, 10), index: parseInt(index)});
    let results = [];

    try {
        await Promise.all(applications.map(async (application) => {
            const job = await Job.findOne({ where: { id: application.jobId } });
            const applicant = await Applicant.findOne({ where: { id: application.applicantId } });

            results.push({application, job, applicant});
        }));

        res.status(200).json({msg: 'success', applications: results});

    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

It seems to work, but feels a bit hacky. Is there a way of querying the through table and getting the associated data from both the Jobs and Applicant tables at the same time?

Thanks!

*EDIT: So I'm trying to return an array of application objects that look something like this:

```
[
    {
        applicationId: application.id,
        companyId: job.companyId,
        company: job.company.name,
        position: job.title,
        applicantId: applicant.id,
        firstName: applicant.firstName,
        lastName: applicant.lastName,
    }, 
    {...}, 
    {...}
]
```

...but I'd like to paginate the application results. So:

`Application.findAll({ limit, index });`

Ideally I'd also then like to be able to order by Job/Applicant properties too

---

**More info:**

So thanks to the help so far it looks like I need to also create a `belongsTo` association for the Application and Job/Applicant so that I can query the Association table and get Job/Applicant data:

```
// Applicants M:N Jobs (through Application)
Applicant.belongsToMany(Job, { through: Application });
Job.belongsToMany(Applicant, { through: Application });

// Set associations so the Application table can be queried directly
Application.belongsTo(Job, { foreignKey: { name: 'jobId' }});
Application.belongsTo(Applicant, { foreignKey: { name: 'applicantId' }});
```

I currently create an application in one of my routes using `applicant.addJob(currentJob);`

// Applicant Model:

```
const Applicant = sequelize.define('applicant', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        allowNull: false
    },
    cvUrl: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: true
    }
});
```

// Job Model:

```
const Job = sequelize.define('job', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    title: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },

    // **snip**

    createdAt: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE(3),
        allowNull: false,
    },
    updatedAt: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE(3),
        allowNull: false,
    }
});
```

// Application Model:

```
const Application = sequelize.define('application', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        notNull: true
    }
});
```

Comment: "Job.findAll({ limit: x, offset: y }) wouldn't find the first y number of applications.".  Do you mean x number of applications (y is offset)??   Do you mean to fetch x number of Jobs and x number of applications within each job?  and max total of x * x records?

Comment: Hi Emma - No, sorry, it is a bit confusing the way I've written it - I'm trying to return x number of applications with y as the offset. The `Job.findAll()` snippet was just to demonstrate that it doesn't seem possible to achieve that by querying one side of the relationship

Comment: The nested queries seem to work correctly, but mean that I can no longer order the query by, for example, the job title or applicant name. That makes me think that I'm possibly approaching the whole query in the wrong way

Comment: It might be possible with subquery but I tried to understand whether you want to fetch Applications by pagination and associated job? or you want to fetch all jobs and subset of Applications with pagination.

Comment: I want to fetch all the Applications (and their related Jobs and Applicants). The problem is that the way I'd usually do it - querying one side of the relationship, getting the applicants, and then creating an 'application' to display doesn't let me order or paginate the results in the way I want. I think I'm going to edit the original question as it isn't very clear. Sorry!

Comment: So basically I'd like to query the Application table and paginate the results. Which the snippet I posted does do, but it now causes the problem that I can't order the results based on say the job title or applicant name, only by the cols in the application table

Comment: hmm.  it doesn't quite make sense yet. Application is a junction table. Each record is a unique pair of ApplicantId and JobId. So when you fetch Application with pagination and get the associated Applicant and Job, you only have 1 Applicant and 1 Job per Application. So there is no ordering within the Application.  I feel like you want to fetch by either Applicant or Jobs but I am not sure.

Maybe show us the outcome json you want to have?  Also, the model definition of all models that is mentioned in question.

Comment: Please clarify what result you want to get and to what model records you need to apply limit, offset and sorting

Comment: Hi @Anatoly, I've just added the result I'm looking for to the OP (& @Emma)

Comment: Thanks @Emma for sticking with me even though I'm not being that clear!

Comment: How do you imagine sorting by `applicant/job` props if there might be several records with different values for one single Application record? Let's say you have 2 records in Applicant for the same Application record with different `lastName` values and one more `Application` record also has two `Applicant` records with different `lastName` values.

Comment: Each application/row in the join table consists of an applicationId, jobId and applicantId, so you wouldn't be able to have 2 applicant records for the same application. Granted you could have 2 applicant records for the same job, but then I'm not sure I understand why that would be different to ordering a table by lastname more generally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirement properly, I think you want to do this way.

This is an example to order by Applicant.

For order by Job, change the `order` option with Job's attribute.

When you use the offset/limit, you need the `order` and the `order` option needs to ensure the ordering is always same and unique.

```js
const applications = await Application.findAll({
    include: [
        {                               
            model: Job
        },
        {
            model: Applicant
        }
    ],
    subQuery: false,
    order: [
        ['Applicant', 'lastName'],
        ['Applicant', 'firstName']
        // lastName & firstName is not enough to get a unique order.
        // In order to make sure the order is always same and pagination works properly,
        // you should add either order by id or createdAt/updatedAt. 
        ['Applicant', 'createdAt', 'desc']  
    ],
    offset: index,
    limit,
    raw: true     // To flatten the response.
});
```

Comment: Hi Emma, sorry for the slow reply, long weekend! Thanks for the response - this is similar to what I tried (minus the ordering), but I always received a `SequelizeEagerLoadingError: job is not associated to application!` error - which is why I thought I couldn't query the through table the way I wanted. The same is happening with the code above (thanks for the commenting though, v useful!)

Comment: No worries. Hope you had a great weekend. This error, `"xxx" is not associated to "yyy"` means you are missing any associations from yyy to xxx.  That means you need any of `hasMany`,  `belongsTo` or `belongsToMany` needs to be defined as `yyy.{associationFunction}(xxx)`.  In your case, you need `Application.belongsTo(Job);` Same for Applicant model. `Application.belongsTo(Applicant);`

Comment: This is a little confusing but you have `belongsToMany` from `Job` or `Applicant`. but this is needed when you are querying from `Job` or `Applicant`.  Easy way to remember is you need association `xxx.(belongsTo/hasMany/belongsToMany)` when you want to do `xxx.(findOne/findAll/etc)`.

Comment: Weekend was great thanks! Hope yours was too. So is it fairly normal to have an M-M association between 2 models through a table, and have associations between each of those models *and* the through table itself? Just never came across that in the docs or when taking intro courses

Comment: Only if you need to query "from" the through table, you need the association from the through table.

Comment: Ok great, thanks! Although adding `Application.belongsTo(Job)` and `Application.belongsTo(Applicant)` has led to an error `SequelizeDatabaseError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''0', '8'' at line 1`

Comment: Assume that's due to not setting up the assoc properly:

Prior to adding `Application.belongsTo(Job)` / `Application.belongsTo(Applicant)` to my code, my `Applications` table had the columns `id`, `createdAt`, `applicantId`, `jobId` - can I create the new associations using the last two columns? Eg: `Application.belongsTo(Job, { foreignKey: { name: jobId } })`?

Do I also have to manually find the `Application` and create the associations between it and the `Job` and `Applicant` every time I create an Application with, for example, `job1.addApplicant(applicant1)`?

Comment: Think I found the reason for that error, but it just resulted in `TypeError: Cannot read property '_modelAttribute' of undefined` (*Edit*: Nvm, that was just a missing comma in the order clause)

Comment: `Application.belongsTo(Job, { foreignKey: { name: jobId } })`, this is correct way to set the association.  However, to be able to help you further, could you add the model definition for `Job`, `Applicant` and `Application`?

Comment: Sure, I'm just adding more detail to my question, thanks!

Comment: Btw, at least your find query is resolved?  Now you have issues with inserting the data?  If so, perhaps we should split the question.  This question is about querying with ordering.  If you have troubles with add data, let's open the new question, specifically for adding data.

Comment: You know what, I'm not even entirely sure. The error comes immediately after a select statement, so maybe not? I've updated the OP now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241367/discussion-between-emma-and-nickw).

Answer (score 1):

With the combination of previous answers

```
Applicant.belongsToMany(Job, { through: Application ,as:'jobs'});
Job.belongsToMany(Applicant, { through: Application,as:'applicants' })
```

with these aliases, you can include both into the application

```
const applications = await Application.findAll({
include: [
    {model: Job, as:'jobs',  where: {id: application.jobId}},
    {model: Applicant, as:'applicants' where:{id: application.jobId}}
],
limit,
raw: true
});
```

also, you can set include as if applicant and job has an association

```
{model: Job, as:'jobs',  where: {id: application.jobId} 
   include:[{model:Applicant as:'applicants'}]
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Sertachak, but trying to include those models into the application query results in an error stating there's no association between application/job application/association. Have added a bit more detail to the OP

Answer (score 0):

You can give aliases tou your associations and just get

```
Applicant.belongsToMany(Job, { through: Application ,as:'jobs'});
Job.belongsToMany(Applicant, { through: Application,as:'applicants' });
```

Then you'll be able to use a simple include
for example Get the job and its applicants with one single query

```
 const job = await Job.findOne({
    where: { id: application.jobId },
    include: ['applicants'],
  });
```

in your job object you'll get an array of applicants .

More reference for that in [here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#defining-an-alias)